# Find the last occurrence of certain value in column

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, vba

I am converting a vba script to google app script and am struggling to find the best way to get the last occurrence of a variable in a column.

In vba, I am able to do the following:

```
Worksheets("variants").Range("A:A").Find(what:=productid, after:=Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
```

In google app script, however, the [find](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126) function doesn't have the searchdirection parameter. I could solve it by iterating through the values of the column using my own function, however, that is slow. Is there an alternative on how to accomplish this using the google spreadsheet native functions?

Comment: you could do it in a cell like `=ArrayFormula(max(row(A:A)*(A:A=B2)))`... however... i dont think it will help you :/

Comment: cool, ok, i got around not being able to use the native functions in the app script, so this is exactly what i needed

Comment: oh... ok... glad i could help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLastProductRow(ProductId){
  return runFunction('=ArrayFormula(max(row(A:A)*(A:A='+ProductId+')))')
}

//run spreadsheet function
function runFunction(formula){
  var cell = pvs.getRange("Z1");
  cell.setFormula(formula);
  return cell.getValue();
}
```